# Base 12 input and output without ^^ or BaseForm

Tags: output-formatting, input, number-bases

I would like to be able to enter numbers and have them interpreted in base 12 and output in base 12. For example, I want

```
13+A
```

to produce

```
21
```

Of course, Mathematica allows the use of other bases:

```
BaseForm[12^^13 + 12^^A, 12]
```

returns

```
21_12
```

but I would rather not have to enter the extra stuff.

I imagine I would need to alter my environment similar to below. I don't mind breaking things. I just want to be able to do simple arithmetic in base 12.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated to work with strings instead of boxes**

One idea is to create a "Duodecimal" style that automatically interprets strings as base 12 integers, and outputs the result in [`BaseForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseForm). This is an example stylesheet that does this:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Duodecimal",StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Input"]],
            CellEvaluationFunction->Function[
                BaseForm[
                    With[
                        {
                        g = StringReplace[
                            #,
                            {
                                StartOfString~~i:DigitCharacter~~m:{DigitCharacter,"A","B"}..~~r___:>"12^^"<>i<>m<>" "<>r,
                                StartOfString~~m:{DigitCharacter,"A","B"}..~~EndOfString:>"12^^"<>m
                            }
                        ]&
                        },

                        ToExpression @ StringReplace[
                            #,
                            {
                            f:(DigitCharacter..~~"."~~DigitCharacter...):>f,
                            l:WordCharacter.. :> g[l]
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    12
                ]
            ],
            DefaultFormatType->"RawInputForm"
        ]
    },
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
]
```

Note that I use `DefaultFormatType->"RawInputForm"` so that there is no space between the 1 and the A in an input like "1A". Both [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) and [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) will display an input like 1A with a space.

Using "RawInputForm" means that the input is a simple string (as you can tell by using `Show Expression`) from the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) menu. I originally tried to convert the string to boxes, and then processed the boxes so that the input was in base 12. However, this didn't quite work (there were issues with both multiplication and powers), so now I instead process the input string. I avoided processing real numbers (as indicated by a `.`) and I converted words to a base 12 string if the word started with an integer or the whole word consisted strictly of duodecimal characters.
Finally, I included a [`BaseForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseForm) wrapper in the output. You can always eliminate this and use your $Post method instead.

To use this style, enter Alt-0 and type in Duodecimal. If desired, one could also give it a [`MenuCommandKey`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MenuCommandKey), or add a [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) to the "Input" style.

Here is a screen shot of a couple examples:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the output side of things the following seems to work:

```
$PrePrint = Replace[n_Integer :> IntegerString[n, 12]]
```

Then

```
12^^13 + 12^^A
```

produces

```
21
```

I don't know whether something similar can be done with `$PreRead`. I don't mind losing my strings starting with `a` and `b`.

Comment: The problem with $PreRead is that it is already after tokenization stage and when you type 2-F-(Ctrl+6)-2 and expect (2F)^2, you won't get it.

Comment: F? Hexadecimal? Do you mean 2F^2?

Comment: Sorry, meant A or B, doesn't matter what base. And I meant to show short form of `(12^^2A)^12^^2`